# Find all lines without a double string

Tags: regex, string, vim, double, pattern-matching

I want to find all lines **without** a double number.

I know how to find the double number on a line:

```
/\zs\(\d\d\d\.\d\d\).*\1\ze
```

But I don't know how to find lines *without* this double number (the negative matching of above regex)

This one does partially what I want:

```
/^\(\(.*\d\d\d\.\d\d.*\)\{2,}\)\@!.*\1.*$
```

p.e.:
the line `201.12 text 201.12` is NOT found --> OK
but also the line `201.12 text 203.12` is NOT found --> NOT OK
Last line has to be found because the numbers are NOT the same.
What did I wrong?

Comment: Format of each number is `3 digit . 2 digit` ?

Comment: Try `/^\(.*\(\d\+\.\d\+\).*\1\)\@!.*$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, don't work in above example.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `v/\(\d\d\d\.\d\d\).*\1/command` would probably do what you want.

Comment: @FDinoff: That would search for repeated groups. OP wants to negate such pattern.

Comment: @noob thats why its passed to the `:v` command (`:g!`)

Comment: @FDinoff: Okay. Am not good with vim. Sorry !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/^.*$\&\%(.*\(\d\{3}\.\d\{2}\).*\1\)\@!.*
```

or with magic:

```
/\v^.*&%(.*(\d{3}\.\d{2}).*\1)@!.*
```

#### EDIT:

Actually, `\&` is no need. This one is simpler:

```
\v^%(.*(\d{3}\.\d{2}).*\1)@!.*
```

Comment: Can you please explain what `$\&` does?

Comment: `\&` lets you match its two sides at the same time: here it matches a whole line, and at the same time, something which not contains twice the same number. Actually, I just noticed that it's no use here... I made an edit

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with this:

```
.*(\d\d\d\.\d\d).*(?=\d\d\d\.\d\d)(?!\1).*
```

The ?= is a not consuming operator. It looks for the regex on the right side of the equals symbol but leaves it to be checked by the following expressions. Because of this it test the string again. Then it checks if the first match is included. If it is found, the query fails (because of the?!) - if it is not found it goes ahead to the next .*

Comment: Fails test for `201.12 text 203.12 201.12`.

Comment: True. In detail my regex only test if there are two different numbers in the string - not if any number exists twice. Let me think about this...

Answer (score 1):

This one is a bit tricky. Here is lookahead based pattern that lets you do that assuming each line has 2 decimal numbers:

```
/\v^((\d{3}\.\d{2})@!.)*(\d{3}\.\d{2})(.*\3)@!.*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qQ0wF5/2)